# Silent Push Notifications. iOS

Tags: ios, iphone, ipad, firebase

I have a problem with Apple Silent Push Notifications. After some amount of time (24 hours+) app stops receiving silent push notifications. During that time device is not rebooted or app force quitted. It is just leaved. I'm using Firebase messaging. Have you had the same? Below is my payload:

APN payload:

```
["aps": {"content-available"=1},
"verify_url":"http://example.com"]
```

Firebase payload:

```
{ "to":"...",
  "priority": "high",
  "data":{"verify_url":"http://example.com"},
  "content_available":true }
```

Thank you forward!

Comment: How are you verifying that it stops receiving them?

Comment: @ThePumpingLama it should load data from verify_url but it didn't.

Comment: Silent pushes are not always delivered immediately like foreground pushes. There are frequently delays which can be hours. This happens particularly if the device has powered down and been dormant for a while. It may not be that they are not being delivered, just that they are being delayed. (Also of course they are not delivered if the app is terminated)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is the reason, but your payload should look like `{"aps":{"content-available"=1}}`. You have a `content_available` instead of a `content-available`.

Comment: Payload is correct. It was my typing error in Stackoverflow. Edited